# Firebase Auth - null is not an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

After logging in, I'm automatically moving to `Tabs` screen.
But `Tabs.js` shows me this error: `null is not an object (evaluation 'currentUser.uid')`.
And on every other screen that in `Tabs` shows this error.

Code:

```
const databaseUserName = firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .get()
        .then(documentSnapshot => {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
                setName(documentSnapshot.data().name);
                setGroupID(documentSnapshot.data().group);
            }
        });
```

Routes.js:

```
const Routes = () => {

    // const [user, setUser] = useState();
    const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('#FF573300');
        StatusBar.setTranslucent(true)
    }, []);

    const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
        setUser(user);
        if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
        return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
    }, []);

    if (initializing) return null;

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

I'm initializing the user, I really don't know how it can be null

Comment: Apparently, `currentUser` is null. Can you show us how `currentUser` is defined?

Comment: I'm defining the current user at the top of the code like this: `const currentUser = auth().currentUser;`

Comment: Since that's resulting in null, apparently no user is logged in. If that's expected, you'll need to decide what you want to do if there is no user. If that's unexpected, you'll need to show us the code that you think ensures the user must exist.

Comment: I'm showing the screens with this code after logging in, how is it possible that user is null?

Comment: Best guess is that there's a bug in the code that causes the screen to show too early. But without seeing the code that controls when this screen is shown, how can i know?

Comment: I have added the routes.js

Comment: And after reloading the app, It doesn't show this error.

Comment: Try using `auth().currentUser` instead of `user` in  your conditional render in Routes.js. Since `currentUser` is null even after logging in its possible that `user` is being updated to an empty object (or some other non-nullish value) while auth isnt truly changing

Comment: It still shows this error: `null is not an object` on `tabs.js`

Comment: `currentUser` should be defined within the function. If defined at the top level then the value isnt recalculated every re-render